# Buffers on the Stack in Assembly

Tags: assembly, buffer

I have the following simple code

```
   void test() {
        char buffer[20];
        return 0;
    }

    int main() {
        test();
    }
```

The assembly it outputs is

Disassembly of section .text:

```
0000000000000000 <test>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   5:   c3                      retq

0000000000000006 <main>:
   6:   55                      push   %rbp
   7:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   a:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
   f:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  14 <main+0xe>
  14:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  15:   c3                      retq
```

I do I surmise the buffer size from this assembly? It doesn't seem like a lot is going on with the stack.

Comment: The compiler optimizes out the local since it's not being referenced. Try doing something with it.

Comment: Bingo   4:   c6 45 e0 63             movb   $0x63,-0x20(%rbp), but what does this instruction actually mean? -0x20 + %rpb = 0x63?

Comment: You have presumably written `buffer[x] = 99;` or similar.

Comment: Stores `0x63` into memory at address [rbp-32]. It's abusing some stack redzone I suppose, if you put bigger local variable like `buffer[400];`, it will also produce `sub rsp,<local vars paddded size>` instruction to reserve more space at stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://godbolt.org/ to real time explore the resulting machine code of C++ source:
(I use Intel syntax.. switch if off, in case you want AT&T)

```
void test() {
    char buffer[400];
    buffer[0] = 0;
    return;
}
```

Compiles to:

```
test():
    ; {
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 280    ; reserves more space at stack for local variables

    ; buffer[0] = 0;
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-400], 0

    ; return; .. sort of .. or just padding
        nop

    ; }
        leave
        ret
```

---

A proper C compiler will not try to "a lot to go on", instead it will try to achieve all defined/desired behaviour of your C source with minimal amount of instructions... Actually I think with high enough optimization level it would remove the `test()` call completely, as it doesn't do anything and the compiler knows it.

---

edit: yeah, with -O3 the gcc will produce only `rep ret` for whole `test()`. Works. (`rep` is used for older AMD CPUs to not choke prefetch queue when single `ret` follows some conditional branch jump ... You can treat it as simple `ret`, it's just additional junk byte to make `ret` 2 byte opcode).